# TypeORM foreign key not showing on a find call

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

```
export class Contact extends BaseEntity {
  ...
  @ManyToOne(() => User, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: User;
  ...
}

const repo = new Repository<User> ();
const response = await repo.findAll();
console.log(response);

console.log:
[
 Contact {
  id: 1,
  ...
 },
 Contact {
  id: 2,
  ...
 }
]
```

I am trying to fetch all the columns included on my `Contact`, but I only able to fetch the columns that does not have any relationship from the other entity.
It does not include user_id columns. Why can't to get foreign key for instance?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
export class Contact extends BaseEntity {
  ...
  // add column explicitly here
  @Column({ name: 'user_id' })
  userId: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, { nullable: false })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: User;
  ...
}
```

You should add `userId` column explicitly and pass this column name to `@JoinColumn` decorator.

Hope it helps.

Here is discussion about it.
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/586#issuecomment-311282863

Comment: Btw, should I add `{ nullable: false }` to `userId` column?

Comment: Sure I believe you could add whatever you want ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can set `eager: true` in order to load User with the find command

```
 @ManyToOne(() => User, { nullable: false, eager: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'user_id' })
  user: User;
```

Link: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/relations

Comment: "eager: true" => now I can see foreign keys in response body. Thanks !