# overcome MustBeEntityError: Cannot save, given value must be an entity, instead "undefined" is given

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I would like to specify a one to one relationship for User and Profile. User owns the relationship, we can say that a user has a profile. But the problem is when I run the code I get the error message:

```
{ name: 'Greg', password: '123', email: 'greg@here.com' }
MustBeEntityError: Cannot save, given value must be an entity, instead "undefined" is given.
```

It is expecting user.profile to be defined in postman, but the problem is that I'm building a SPA with React at the frontend  so at the time when the user signs up, the profile does not even exists yet. To solve this issue , I thought about  giving  a default value for profile when I call the route which creates the user and then later create the profile and update the profile for that user through another route.

this is my User.ts:

```
@Entity("User")
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @Column("number")
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column("text")
  name: string;

  @Column("text")
  password: string;

  @Column("text")
  email: string;

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62460079/typeorm-foreign-key-not-showing-on-a- 
  find-call
  @Column("number", { default: -1, name: "profileId" })
  profileId: number;

  @OneToOne(() => Profile, { cascade: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: "profileId" })
  profile: Profile;

}

and this is my Profile.ts:

@Entity("Profile")
export class Profile extends BaseEntity {
  @Column("number")
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column("text", { nullable: true })
  gender: string;

  @Column("text", { nullable: true })
  occupation: string;

  @OneToOne(() => User, (user) => user.profile) // specify inverse side as a second parameter
  user: User;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To save, you will need to make the object an instance of the entity class you want to save. `Repository#create` can help you create an instance with initial values easily.

```js
const userRepo = entityManager.getRepository(User);
await userRepo.save(
  userRepo.create({ name: 'Greg', password: '123', email: 'greg@here.com' })
);
```

See also: https://typeorm.io/#/repository-api

Alternatively, you can use `Repository#insert` if you don't care about the returned result.

```js
await userRepo.insert({ name: 'Greg', password: '123', email: 'greg@here.com' });
```

Comment: it will complain, because profile needs to be set ie  user.profile. but I don't have the profile yet,when I create a user, how can I set it.

Comment: In TypeORM's one-to-one relationship, one side of the relationship can be null. If you don't want to save the user in advance, save the object in JavaScript memory and then save on TypeORM later.

Comment: Usually the first thing the user does is sign up, this is where I create the User entity with Express route. But at that time we don't have the profile for that user yet. So should I save the user information in local or session storage

Answer (score 0):

The controller is expecting **@Body()** parameter

```
@Post('/save')
saveQuestion(@Body()createQuestionDto:CreateQuestionDto):Promise<Question>
{
    return this.questionService.saveQuestion(createQuestionDto)
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your solution further, like where the `@Body` decorator comes from.